# Servlet call from HTML form through script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

I am trying simple program which receive receipt number from user end and send to servlet once user clicks button. Calling servlet through script.

I could call servlet, but not able to get the user input at servlet end using req.getparameter. I am receiving null value. Please help me on what i am missing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script>
        function showCustomer() {
          var xmlhttp;
          var value1 = document.getElementById("num").value; 
  
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
              }
          };
          //xmlhttp.open("GET", "callserv1?q="+str, true);
          //xmlhttp.send();
          xmlhttp.open("GET", "callserv1", true);
          xmlhttp.send();
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action=""> 
        Receipt no
        <input type="text" name="num" id="num"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="showCustomer()" value ="call"/>
    </form>
    <p id="demo">Customer info will be listed here...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class callserv1 extends HttpServlet
{
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("This Example demonstrates, using Ajax request to Access Servlet ");
    String num =  request.getParameter("num");
    out.println("i am in" +num); 
  }
}
```

Comment: You are making a call to your servlet callserv1 but you are never passing along your parameter. You must get your parameter and pass it in the request. You are not automatically getting everything from the form as you are not submitting the form, you are doing a separate GET request to your servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your `showCustomer()` method you need to pass your value. It seems like you have made some attempts in getting the value and in your commented out section pass it along, but there are two things there:

1. You are not passing along the correct parameter, in your case `value1`
2. You have named the parameter something differently, it should be named `num`.

Based on this, this code should work better for you.

```
function showCustomer() {
    var xmlhttp;
    var value1 = document.getElementById("num").value; 

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "callserv1?num="+value1, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It works. Could you please tell me how to get the value back to html from servlet, and get it display in text box.

Comment: Looking at your code snippet: It seems to me you already have the code to put the result in the element with id `demo`. Is that not working?

Comment: No. I have two result data at servlet side, say String Docno and String Docdate. I am getting underfined value at html side

Comment: you are using `this` in your code, from the examples I have seen you should use your `xmlhttp` object. I have edited my answer.

Comment: yes i have tried what you have suggested. But i am getting undefined value.

Comment: Then you probably need to raise that as a new questions as although it is related to your end solution, it is not part of this question. Be sure to include code and details on what behavior you expect and what behavior you get.